# How to insert the string value in sql lite database?

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite, subprocess

The following code shows error

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('test.db')
url=http://www.google.com    
with con:    
   cur = con.cursor()    
   cur.execute("CREATE TABLE info(Id INT, Url_Name varchar(55))")
   cur.execute("INSERT INTO info VALUES(1,url)")
```

I tried with %s  but it still not working,,,,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`url=http://www.google.com` is invalid syntax, but presumably you have realised that and have changed it to a string, i.e.

url = 'http://www.google.com'

Even after that, you are trying to insert a non-string value `url` into the `Url_Name` column. The query:

```
"INSERT INTO info VALUES(1,url)"
```

You can make that work by using a parameterised query:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO info VALUES(1, ?)", (url,))
```

Also, after the first run of your program, the `info` table will exist, and subsequent runs of your program will fail (unless you drop the table elsewhere). Alternatively you can add the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause to the `CREATE TABLE` query:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info(Id INT, Url_Name varchar(55))")
```

Comment: whenever i use this parameterised query ,i get the output                                                                                     (1,u'http://www.google.com') ,,i dont know where from u came

Comment: The 'u' signifies that the string is a `unicode` string. sqllite returns TEXT fields as unicode, so that's why you see the 'u'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mhawke for the answer,but
whenever i use  parameterised query:

cur.execute("INSERT INTO info VALUES(1, ?)", (url,))
  I get the output as (1,u'http://www.google.com')
I do not know where from the u came

i used

```
cur = con.cursor()    
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM info")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row*
```